# text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't appear to be working for SVG text

Tags: css, svg

Please refer below SVG code sample, where I want to apply an ellipsis for long text, which seems not to be working as we know CSS is not applied to SVG.

Please suggest any alternate solution to applying CSS to an SVG element.

```
    <g font-size="18" font-family="'ArialMT'" style="
        text-decoration: none;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 80px;
        height: 32px;
    ">
     <text transform="translate(74.342 228.4)" style="
        text-decoration: none;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 10px;
        height: 32px;
    ">
     Imran Shaikh dfdfd f dfdf d fd fd fd f df df d fd fd f df d fd fd 
    </text>
    </g>
    </svg>
```